# How to change the size of a Django form label

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following form:

`forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, HiddenInput, CharField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

import re
from django import forms
from cal.models import Event
from project.models import Project

class EventForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    class Meta:
        model = Event
        widgets = {
            'event_type': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'size': '4',
                    'style': 'font-size:13px;'
                }
            ),
        }
        labels = {
            'equipments': 'Equipment', 'event_type': 'Type',
        }
        fields = '__all__'
```

And in my `template.html` I render the content of the form like this:

```
    {% bootstrap_field event_form.title layout='horizontal' size='small' %}
    {% bootstrap_field event_form.description layout='horizontal' size='small' %}
    {% bootstrap_field event_form.event_type layout='horizontal' size='small' %}
```

I would like the label font size to be 13px; Apparently `'style': 'font-size:13px;'` works only for the content of the field, not for the label.

Is there a way to add styles **only to label** or label and field (both)?

I have been reading the [documentation here](https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-field) but it is not clear to me how to change the style, it seems like only classes can be changed...?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly try to target the `control-label` class in your CSS file and assign it the CSS properties of your choice.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I would like to avoid manipulating css directly.