# How to add custom CSS for form labels to Django forms?

Tags: python, django

I have a django form for which I need to increase the font size of the labels. Based on [this StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69172643/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-django-form-label), what I need to do is add a CSS class and apply it to the control-label. How do I actually go about doing that?

My form is populated like so:

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        fields_to_add = {

        # many fields here, but all in this format. Removed for brevity.
            'purchase_order_number': forms.ChoiceField(
                label="Purchase Order",
                choices=purchase_order_numbers),
        }

        self.fields.update(fields_to_add)

        self = add_classes(self)
```

The `add_classes` code is as follows:

```py
def add_classes(self):
    """Add styling to form inputs."""
    for key, value in self.fields.items():
        self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control',  # <- this is what I expect to change
             'style': 'font-size: large',}
            )
    return(self)
```

I assume I need to modify `add_classes` to add some form of `control-label` or a custom class like   `{'class': 'form-control control-label',`, but once I do that, where do I actually specify the size of my labels? They are not specified in my HTML template.

Edit: based on the suggestion, I have created a file named `customFormStyle.css` with the following contents:

```css
.form-control {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

and in the HTML of my form have included a link to that CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main/static/main/css/customFormStyle.css"/>
```

...but my form does not reflect the change.

Here is my template, for context (`{{form}}` is where the form is passed in, I do not have direct access to the HTML for the fields):

```html
{% extends "main/_one_column.html" %}
{% comment %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% endcomment %}
{% block maincontent %}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main/static/main/css/customFormStyle.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <form action="" method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form}}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add a custom class to your field, then you must add a css style, it can be from a file or directly in your html.

In this case, the class is 'form-control', so the following style would suffice

```
<style>
   .form-control {
     height: 50px;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have attempted to link the CSS style via file and have updated the description to reflect my attempt, but the change does not appear to be working quite yet. Any additional ideas?

Comment: You can verifying if the style is applying to the field in your browser developer console. If appear crossed out, it should suffice add "!important" (without cuotes) to the style, otherwise, you have an error on the class name or style name or the style file is wrong imported.